# laravel controller doesn't exist though it exists

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

This is the route

```
Route::get('contact', 'Pages@contact');
```

The is the controller:

```
<?php
class PagesController extends BaseController {


  public function contact()
  {
    return View::make('hello');
  }

}
```

This is the error message

```
500 Internet error
ReflectionException
Class Pages does not exist
```

I am using laravel 4.2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your controller name in the route given below:

```
Route::get('contact', 'Pages@contact');
```

Should be

```
Route::get('contact', 'PagesController@contact');
```

Because the controller name is `PagesController` not `Pages`. So `Class Pages does not exist` error is rising and it's logical because the `Pages` class doesn't exist.